# Reading/editing a file from a certain point

Tags: java, file, parsing, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am currently attempting to write a small piece of Java that needs to read through a file, searching for a certain line to change. The issue is that the line to change is not unique in the file as it is part of an XML-like structure so is nested inside another tag.

For example:

```
<tag1>Tag Text</tag1>
    <example>Value</example>

<tag2>Tag Text</tag2>
    <example>Value</example> //Want to change only this Value.

<tag3>Tag Text</tag3>
    <example>Value</example>
```

In this example, I want to change only the Value in the example tag under `<tag2>` without changing the other values.

So I am trying to search for `<tag2>` first, once that is found I search for `<value>`, edit that value and then leave the rest of the file as is.

Currently I am using a BufferedReader/Writer to copy the file to a temp file, changing a value, and then deleting the old file, replacing it with the new one.

See code below:

```
public class Replace {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Replace().replace();
   }

   public void replace() {

    //All input data to be changed, testing purposes.
    String rootFolder = "Some root";
    String fileName = "some filename";
    String newValue = "<Value>New Value</Value>";

    //Strings to find location in the file that needs to be amended.
    String firstFileLine = "<tag2>";
    String secondFileLine = "<Value>";

    String oldFileName = rootFolder + fileName;
    String tmpFileName = "temp.txt";

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
         String line, secondLine;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(firstFileLine)){
            //This is an attempt to try solve it, but this still replaced all <Value> tags in the file
               while ((secondLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (secondLine.contains(secondFileLine))
                        secondLine = secondLine.replace(secondFileLine, newValue);
                    bw.write(secondLine+"\n");  
                }
            }
            bw.write(line+"\n");           
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         return;
      } finally {
         try {
            if(br != null)
               br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
         try {
            if(bw != null)
               bw.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
      }
      // Once everything is complete, delete old file..
      File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);
      oldFile.delete();

      // And rename tmp file's name to old file name
      File newFile = new File(tmpFileName);
      newFile.renameTo(oldFile);

   }
}
```

Is this the best way to be going about this issue? Any other suggestions also welcomed!

Thanks everyone in advance!

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you need to read the old file, do the replacement and write it back. The piece that is incorrect in your current algorithm is that in the while loop you need to stop when you reach the end of tag2.

Also if the content is XML you should consider using an XML parser to do this operation.

```
    while ((secondLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (secondLine.contains(endOfFirstLine)) {
            bw.write(secondLine+"\n"); 
            break;
        }

        if (secondLine.contains(secondFileLine))
            secondLine = secondLine.replace(secondFileLine, newValue);
        bw.write(secondLine+"\n");  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure I fully understand though. Will I still need to nest this new `while` loop within the original `while` and `if` statement? Or replace the two? Also, I'm assuming `endOfFirstLine` just needs to equal the last few characters of that first tag I'm searching for?

Comment: Looking back in the file at more detail, I haven't described the tag system properly. I have now edited the tag structure to represent the file a bit better.

Comment: I have only added a condition in your original loop to stop the processing when you encounter the end of the first tag that you wanted and not continue to replace all values till the end. This is because your original code will replace all values till the end of the file after encountering the first tag1 element.